# How do I flip a lens from a catalog in Zemax?

Tags: cad, modeling

I am pretty new to this ray tracing software. It is simple to add custom surfaces and insert lenses from a catalog, but I can't figure out how to flip left-right a component without having to modify each surface manually.

This would be useful for instance using plano-concave lenses for collimation to reduce aberrations.

Can someone help me out? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is a useful feature. I will assume you are using the sequential mode.

1. Select the surfaces you want to flip.
2. Go to Tools > Modify > Reverse Elements (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>).
3. Click OK.